# Flutter Achieve Sliverappbar Behaviour like telegram

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, sliverappbar

Here is the Gif how the SliverAppbar looks.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ud51yipwnjKjxUcF1dju4F-n2F8/view?usp=sharing
Any hint or help appreciated

Comment: 404 image not found

Comment: image not found

Comment: @pskink  ink updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a source on GitHub that has already done this. Here are the links:

[GitHub Source](https://github.com/FabioXimenes/telegram_profile_animation)

I hope it helps.